# docker network create error "numerical result out of range"

Tags: docker, docker-network

Has anyone gotten this? Here is my command:

```
docker network create \
  --opt com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade=true \
  --opt com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc=true \
  --opt com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4=0.0.0.0 \
  --opt com.docker.network.bridge.name=dockerbridge123456789 \
  --opt com.docker.network.driver.mtu=1500 \
  -d bridge \
  mydockerdockerbridge
```

Here is the response:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to check bridge interface existence: numerical result out of range
```

Answer (score 8):

Turns out `com.docker.network.bridge.name` length is limited to 15 characters.

This works:

```
docker network create \
  --opt com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade=true \
  --opt com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc=true \
  --opt com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4=0.0.0.0 \
  --opt com.docker.network.bridge.name=dockerbridge123 \
  --opt com.docker.network.driver.mtu=1500 \
  -d bridge \
  mydockerdockerbridge
```

Adding a '4' to the end of `dockerbridge123` doesn't work.

:o